# Efficient inference of 3D deep learning model (pytorch)

Tags: memory, deployment, deep-learning, pytorch, cpu

I am trying to use a Pytorch 3D UNet for inference (from here: https://github.com/wolny/pytorch-3dunet) which receives images of size (96, 96, 96). I would like to use it on CPU instances, but I am getting very high memory usages (~18 GB). After researching on the subject I found out that this was due to the way convolutions are implemented on CPU (see https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-high-memory-demand/2798/5). I thus have the following questions:

1. Is there a way to use a more memory-efficient implementation of the convolution in Pytorch?
2. How can I optimize my model for CPU inference? I saw that some tools like AWS Neo, Intel OpenVINO, etc. exist; could they solve my problem?
3. Does Tensorflow have a similar problem for using convolutions on CPU?
4. Any other tip, link on how to deploy such models in an efficient way is welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: By "deployment", do you also mean training, or does it solely include inference? The discussion seems to be talking about the former, in which case I think the title might be a bit misleading. If it is only for inference, make sure you do not stare any activations and use eval mode.

Comment: Only inference, I have adapted the title and description to be more clear! What do you mean by "stare" activations? I use eval mode and torch.no_grad().

Comment: Exactly that ;-) `torch.no_grad()` gets often overlooked and your question didn't state it before. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

You could benchmark your model's performance with [DNN-Bench](https://github.com/ToriML/DNN-bench) and choose the best inference engine for your application and your hardware. You might need to convert your model to [ONNX](https://github.com/onnx/tutorials#converting-to-onnx-format) first.